# WCF Net.tcp service randomly faults

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

This code is slightly modified and almost taken straight from examples off the internet of getting a net.tcp duplex service running with a publish / subscribe mechanism. This works great for awhile but clients randomly fault the channel being used to communicate. Some clients are still good for communication 24 - 48 hours before faulting. Question: Does anyone know why the socket is randomly being aborted or even how to find out what exactly is causing exception in the error logs?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;


    namespace WcfService1
    {

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallBack))]
    interface IService
    {
        //The Alert Server Function called by the Client
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SubscribeToBeNotifiedServer(string EmpID);


        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void UpdatePricingServer(string ReservationID, string CustomerID);


        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessageToNotifyOther(string From, string To, string Message);


    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IClientCallBack
        {
            [OperationContract()]
            [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
            void UpdatePricingClient(string FromReservationID, string CustomerID );

            //The Alert Server Function called by the Client
            [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
            void SubscribeToBeNotifiedClient();

            [OperationContract()]
            [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
            void ReceiveMessage(string From, string Message);


        }


    [ServiceBehavior( ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,UseSynchronizationContext =   false,  InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true )]
    [CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]     
    class Service1 : IService
        {
          public Service1()
          {



          }

          public void SubscribeToBeNotifiedServer(string EmpID)
          {
              var added = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallBack>();

              var st = OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.State;

              var asdf1 = OperationContext.Current.Host.State;

              if (!subscribers.Select(x => x.CallBackInformation).Contains(added))
              {
                  subscribers.Add(new ClientInfo(added, OperationContext.Current, EmpID));

                  OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += new EventHandler(Channel_Faulted);

              }
          }          

          private static readonly List<ClientInfo> subscribers = new List<ClientInfo>();  

          public void UpdatePricingServer(string ReservationID, string CustomerID)
           {                  

               try
               {


                   List<ClientInfo> Remove = new List<ClientInfo>();

                   Action<ClientInfo> invoke = delegate(ClientInfo callback)
                   {

    //I wrapped this in its own thread as the entire thread gets torn down if there is an exception 
    // when you call the client. This is true even if its in a try catch the entire thread dies. 

    System.Threading.Thread mythread = new System.Threading.Thread((System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate() {
        try
        {

            var test = (ICommunicationObject)callback.CallBackInformation;

            if (test.State == CommunicationState.Opened && callback.InstanceContext.Host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {



                callback.CallBackInformation.UpdatePricingClient(ReservationID, CustomerID);


            }

            else
            {
                Remove.Add(callback);
            }

        }
        catch (FaultException<InvalidOperationException> exception)
        { }
        catch (FaultException exception)
        { }
        catch (CommunicationException exception)
        { }
    });



    mythread.Start();


    };

                   subscribers.ForEach(invoke);

                   foreach (var temp1 in Remove)
                   {
                       subscribers.Remove(temp1);
                   }





               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {


               }
           }

          public void SendMessageToNotifyOther(string From, string To, string Message)
          {

              try
              {


                  List<ClientInfo> Remove = new List<ClientInfo>();

                  Action<ClientInfo> invoke = delegate(ClientInfo callback)
                  {

                      //I wrapped this in its own thread as the entire thread gets torn down if there is an exception 
                      // when you call the client. This is true even if its in a try catch the entire thread dies. 

                      System.Threading.Thread mythread = new System.Threading.Thread((System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate()
                      {
                          try
                          {

                              var test = (ICommunicationObject)callback.CallBackInformation;

                              if (test.State == CommunicationState.Opened && callback.InstanceContext.Host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                              {


                                  if (callback.EmployeeID == To)
                                  {
                                      callback.CallBackInformation.ReceiveMessage(From, Message);
                                  }

                              }

                              else
                              {
                                  Remove.Add(callback);
                              }

                          }
                          catch (FaultException<InvalidOperationException> exception)
                          { }
                          catch (FaultException exception)
                          { }
                          catch (CommunicationException exception)
                          { }
                      });



                      mythread.Start();


                  };

                  subscribers.ForEach(invoke);

                  foreach (var temp1 in Remove)
                  {
                      subscribers.Remove(temp1);
                  }





              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {


              }
          }



           #region IService Members
           void Channel_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               ICommunicationObject myobj = (ICommunicationObject)sender;

               myobj.Abort();

               myobj.Close();

           }

           void InstanceContext_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    subscribers.Remove(subscribers.Where(x => x.CallBackInformation == sender).FirstOrDefault());
                }
                catch { }
            }

            void Channel_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    subscribers.Remove(subscribers.Where(x => x.CallBackInformation == sender).FirstOrDefault());
                }
                catch { }
            }

            void InstanceContext_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    subscribers.Remove(subscribers.Where(x => x.CallBackInformation == sender).FirstOrDefault());
                }
                catch { }
            }

            void InstanceContext_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    subscribers.Remove(subscribers.Where(x => x.CallBackInformation == sender).FirstOrDefault());
                }
                catch { }
            }



            #endregion
        }

    public class ClientInfo
      {
          IClientCallBack client;

          OperationContext context;

          public ClientInfo(IClientCallBack clientcall, OperationContext Instance, string EmpID)
          {
              this.client = clientcall;

              this.context = Instance;

              this.EmployeeID = EmpID;
          }

          public IClientCallBack CallBackInformation
          {
              get { return client; }
              set { this.client = value; }
          }

          public OperationContext InstanceContext
          {
              get { return context; }
              set { this.context = value; }
          }

          public string EmployeeID;
      }




    }
```

Here is the web.config of the Server

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off">    
    </customErrors>
      </system.web>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <!--WcfService1.IService-->  

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="portSharingBinding" name="MyServiceEndpoint"
          contract="WcfService1.IService">
          <identity>
            <!--<dns value="localhost:808" />-->
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="/mex" kind="mexEndpoint"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://iiswatso/MnetTcp/Service1.svc" />-->
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehavior" >
          <serviceTimeouts />          
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="portSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true" openTimeout="infinite" closeTimeout="infinite" receiveTimeout="infinite" sendTimeout="infinite"    >
          <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="infinite" ordered="True"    enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None"></security>          
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>   
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"></trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>          
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\log\Server3.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>   
  </system.diagnostics>  
</configuration>
```

Here is the tracing log for the server:

```
 <E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
 <EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-05-30T18:11:10.9002453Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="Meridian Reservation System.vshost" ProcessID="10676" ThreadID="21" />
<Channel />
<Computer>JIMMY-PC</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>Meridian Reservation System.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginReadCore(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.PerformOperation(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.SynchronizedAsyncResult`1..ctor(SynchronizedMessageSource syncSource, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(SynchronizedMessageSource syncSource, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(FramingDuplexSessionChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.DuplexClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnBeginTryReceive(TDuplexChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.TryReceiveAsyncResult.BeginInput(ReliableChannelBinder`1 binder, TChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.CompleteTryGetChannel(IAsyncResult result, Boolean&amp; complete)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.Start()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.TryReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(ReliableChannelBinder`1 binder, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.StartReceiving(Boolean canBlock)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.HandleReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnReceiveCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.OnInputComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.OnInputCompleteStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.SynchronizedAsyncResult`1.CompleteWithUnlock(Boolean synchronous, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginReadCore(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.PerformOperation(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.SynchronizedAsyncResult`1..ctor(SynchronizedMessageSource syncSource, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(SynchronizedMessageSource syncSource, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(FramingDuplexSessionChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.DuplexClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnBeginTryReceive(TDuplexChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.TryReceiveAsyncResult.BeginInput(ReliableChannelBinder`1 binder, TChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.CompleteTryGetChannel(IAsyncResult result, Boolean&amp; complete)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.Start()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.TryReceiveAsyncResult..ctor(ReliableChannelBinder`1 binder, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.StartReceiving(Boolean canBlock)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.HandleReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnReceiveCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.OnInputComplete(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1.InputAsyncResult`1.OnInputCompleteStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.SynchronizedAsyncResult`1.CompleteWithUnlock(Boolean synchronous, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Tracing for the client:

```
     <E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-05-30T18:11:02.2488000Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{54830e63-b315-4f74-9455-d9ba50c655c0}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="2716" ThreadID="6" />
<Channel />
<Computer>IISWATSO</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/MNetTcp-1-129828750305652000</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, Nativ
```

Comment: How is this overly broad? The code itself is from sample code from microsoft very very slightly modified. Its the most simplified version of getting a net.tcp duplex service running. I've listed everything I know about the problem here - not a real question? My question is pretty real and pretty clear - why the heck is this simple service randomly faulting.

Comment: When I solve this problem I'll post here.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add that this post took me more time to put together than the time it took for some moderator to close it. I will resolve this issue and post here for other to see. But I will not be using this site anymore. If a question isn't good let the community let me know - not some dictator. Good luck and thanks for all the fish.

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem - although it occurred over a much longer period of time (i.e. the service lasted days or weeks rather than 24 - 48 hours). Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I would find it extremely useful if you had any results to share.

Comment: I've just come across [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/617491/during-security-negotiation-if-the-client-goes-away-wcf-service-is-terminated-timing-dependent#details) which I can reproduce and seems to create the same exception consistently. I'm still looking for work arounds though...

Comment: I'd like to get to the bottom of it - but i've been super busy. I'll post back here when I find something.

Comment: Lewray let me know if you test out your application in Visual Studio 2012 with the .net 4.5 framework. From what I've read in your link that may fix the issue? Thanks for helping out Lewray.

Comment: So, two more things you have to look out for when creating a wcf duplex service you wish to keep up indefinitely. Whatever application pool you use for your nettcp service - make sure recycling is turned off on that application pool. Second, make sure sendtimeout isn't set to infinite. Otherwise the server will never give up on sending to a client even if that client has gone away.

Answer (score 3):

You have atleast 9 empty catch blocks, this means that you are swallowing the errors and are not able to see what error occured.

The first thing that you should do is to put logging code in each catch block to log the error.

From the code you have posted it appears that you are leaving the channel open, that you are not opening the channel, using it and the closing it as soon as possible. Eventually a channel that is left open will enter a faulted state.

Comment: Your comment isn't very clear. I'm leaving the channel open? Yes that's correct, we are generating a list of people to broadcast. Channels left open should not enter a faulted state. Timeout is set to infinity. I can remove the try catches - I was using them to keep the service running in debug mode and seeing when they fell into those categories.

Comment: The problem is that your design is wrong. You cannot hold a connection lopen idenfinatly.

Comment: What prevents you for holding a connection open as long as there isn't an interuption? There is no reason a service needs to be torn down if the connection isn't interupted. With .net remoting I have made services that have stayed up for long periods of time - I wanted to use WCF but that isn't looking promising.

Comment: By the way, when you say my design is wrong - I didn't design this example. I found this example on several places - one place I recall was a Microsoft hosted site. The code I added is not relevant.

Comment: Shiraz Bhaiji, on a side note - thank you for being constructive and actually adding something to this conversation - you are awesome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672061/wcf-duplex-tcp-communication-error